# How do I fix duplicate junit files in Android Studio after fixing the junit compile error?

Tags: junit

I tried searching for an answer with the error code that I received, but found no such luck. I am currently taking the Android Studio for Beginners course, and I am in Lesson 2A, and I have just started, but I'm not able to proceed because of errors. One of them I fixed by adding a bit of code, and another I fixed by replacing the junit 4.12 file (worked last time), but I'm not sure what went wrong  here. I ended up with a duplicate file error, but I can't figure out what to do about it. Whenever I try to search for answers, I end up looking at titles of forum questions talking about META-INF, which I assume isn't really what I'm looking for. I tried looking at a few of those, but they didn't really garner anything that I'm looking for. The following is the error message I received. If you'd like to see code in any of my files, let me know.

```
Error:Execution failed for task':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK junit/runner/smalllogo.gif
File1: C:\Users\58noa\AndroidStudioProjects\JustJava\app\libs\junit-4.12.jar
File2: C:\Users\58noa\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\junit\junit\4.12\2973d150c0dc1fefe998f834810d68f278ea58ec\junit-4.12.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently commenting out the compile junit line in dependencies in the app window fixed it... strange.